# Activate Rails link_to ajax , call with jquery

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have a rails view with these remote link_to's

```
<%= link_to 'next', next_page_path, remote:true %>
<%= link_to 'previous', previous_page_path, remote:true%>
```

I want to make it possible to activate these with the left and right arrow buttons on the keyboard?.  Is there a way to do this without using JQuery "click" function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit: Misread your question, you can bind the link_to to a specific key like so:**

```
<%= link_to 'previous', previous_page_path, :html_options => {:accesskey => "LEFT ARROW"} %>
```

**Old answer (icons):**

What type of icons are you wanting to use? You can make use of the `.html_safe` helper method. Here's an example with a FontAwesome icon:

```
<%= link_to '<i class="fa fa-heart-o"></i>'.html_safe,
    {controller: "users", action: "save_user", user: @user} %>
```

And one without using the helper, using your example:

```
<%= link_to next_page_path do %>
    <i class="fa fa-arrow"></i>
<% end %>
```

In this way if you click the icon, you are redirected to the appropriate view or controller/action.

Comment: Sorry, I think I wrote this question badly.  I want to use the arrow keys on the keyboard.

Comment: Oh oops, maybe try the edited answer if you still need help

Comment: Thanks, that's what i was looking for.